# How do I supply a filter when all I can provide is an Expression

Tags: java, querydsl

How do I create a filter with en Expression.

I am wanting to filter a map and my generated meta schema only allows me to provide an Expression.

```
public final BooleanExpression contains(Expression<Integer> key, Expression<Address> value)
```

My question is how do I create an Expression that filters on the state of value?

I think I can use `Expressions.constant(55)` for the integer but I'm not sure how to build an Expression that say filters for all the Address that have a particular postal (zip) code.

Comment: What do you have in Map<T1,T2>? Couldn't get the exact input and expected output.

Comment: Map<Integer, Address>

Comment: didn't it work to first filter the map and then Expressions.constant(<enteries from filtered map>)?

Answer (score 0):

This should help, first filter the map and then  generate the Expression.

```
Map<Integer, Address> collect = <YOUR_MAP_REFERENCE>.entrySet().stream()
                                .filter(map -> map.getValue().getZipCode() == <ZIP_CODES_TO_BE_FILTERED>)
                                .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue()));

Set<Integer> keys = collect.keySet();
ArrayList<Expression<Address>> list = new ArrayList<Expression<Address>>();

Iterator<Integer> it = keys.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    list.add(Expressions.constant(collect.get(it.next())));
}
//list: final list of Expression<Address>
```

Comment: That's a good idea but the problem is I have 2.5 million rows (So > 2.5 million Addresses)

Comment: I do not have much idea about querydsl and expression, but check if predicate expression helps.